# Why does a method closure on a Class object fail?

Tags: groovy, closures

In groovy it's pretty easy to create a method closure, for example:

```
groovy:000> p = 1.&plus
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@a7981d5
groovy:000> p(3)
===> 4
```

However, for some reason it fails when trying to use an instance of `Class`:

```
groovy:000> List.isInstance([])
===> true
groovy:000> t = List.&isInstance
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@31ca1a68
groovy:000> t([])
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: java.util.List.isInstance() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[]]
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        ...
groovy:000> t = List.class.&isInstance
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@7b34c5ff
groovy:000> t([])
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: java.util.List.isInstance() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[]]
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        ...
```

It's pretty easy to work around this, but I'd like to understand why this happens.  Is there something in the MOP that stops this from working, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a method pointer on instance of `Class` then it has to explicitly use the `doCall()` method provided by `MethodClosure` instead of using the default `call()` of `Closure`.

`doCall` method from `MethodClosure` overrides Closure's `doCall` and intercepts the method call by using `invokeMethod` instead of calling `call()` from `Closure`.

The `MethodClosure` will also work if you explicitly use the `InvokerHelper` which is synonymous to `doCall` in `MethodClosure` or simply `metaClass` List.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

t = List.&isInstance

assert t.owner.simpleName == 'List'
assert t.doCall([]) == true    
assert InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(t.owner).
              invokeStaticMethod(t.owner, 'isInstance', []) == true
assert List.metaClass.invokeStaticMethod(t.owner, 'isInstance', []) == true
```

[invokeStaticMethod](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/MetaObjectProtocol.html#invokeStaticMethod%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) of MOP is used if the object is an instance of `Class`.

On the other hand, `&plus` works appropriately because method pointer is created on a POJO.